# Run CommandLineRunner Bean when ddl-auto is set to create in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, application.properties

I have this CommandLineRunner in my Main class (ReservationprojectApplication)

```
@Bean
    CommandLineRunner run(UserService userService) {
        return args -> {
            userService.saveRole(new Role(null, "ROLE_ADMIN"));
            userService.saveRole(new Role(null, "ROLE_STUDENT"));

            userService.saveUser(new User("administrator", "admin@gmail.com", "t", new ArrayList<>(), Instant.now(), true));
            userService.saveUser(new User("elias", "elias@gmail.com", "t", new ArrayList<>(), Instant.now(), true));

            userService.addRoleToUser("administrator", "ROLE_ADMIN");
            userService.addRoleToUser("elias", "ROLE_STUDENT");
        };
    }
```

Is there a way to only run this code once the ddl-auto is set to create? I don't want to comment this code each time my ddl-auto is set to update.

```
spring:
  # Database properties
  datasource:
    password: blabla
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cegeka_reservation
    username: postgres
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      **ddl-auto: update**
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        show_sql: true
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have access to the property so it is easy enough to check it

```
@Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
private String ddl;

@Bean
CommandLineRunner run(UserService userService) {
  if ("create".equals(ddl) {
    // Rest of your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be using the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation as shown below, which checks if the specified properties have a specific value, for more details about conditional beans with Spring Boot check [the blog post](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/).

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    name = {"spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto"},
    havingValue = "create")
CommandLineRunner run(UserService userService) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hello Birca, thank you for your response, but for some reason it doesn't add my users to the database this way. I think it just skips the condition every time even though my ddl-auto is set to create

Comment: can you run the code in debug mode and check if the code inside the block is executed?